# How to mock the removeChild or appendChild function call in angular directives testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am facing issue in angular directive testing with mocking the dom 
manipulation api's  removeChild or appendChild functions.
directive is created to add/remove the items to dropdown menu.

I have tried mocking the DOM manipulation API's  `removeChild` or 
`appendChild` functions with `jasmine.createSpyObj`, but is not mocking the 
call and the call is going to actual function call and throwing error.

```js
it('TestCase: appMenuDropDown Directive',() => {
    var rendererMock;
    const debugEl: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    rendererMock =  jasmine.createSpyObj('rendererMock',['removeChild']);
    rendererMock.removeChild(); /*mocking removeChild call*/
    const inputEl: HTMLElement = debugEl.querySelector('.list-item');
    inputEl.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(rendererMock.removeChild).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

below is the console error.

> context.js:248 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
>   at MenuDropDownDirective../src/app/directives/menu-drop-down.directive.ts.MenuDropDownDirective.clickListener

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appMenuDropDown]' })
export class MenuDropDownDirective {
    @Input() subMenuContainer: ElementRef;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}
    @HostListener('click') clickListener() {
        const sourceElement: any = this.el.nativeElement;
        const targetElement: any = this.subMenuContainer;
        if (sourceElement.children.length > 1) {
            this.renderer.removeChild(targetElement.parentNode, targetElement);
        } else {
            this.renderer.appendChild(sourceElement, targetElement);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide directive code?

Comment: @snehapatil : This should be tested in a different way. Since your directive requires `ElementRef` as `@Input` , so you need to create a Test Component and use this directive and write test cases. Let me know if you find solution using my suggestion.  Cheers :)

Comment: You create a mock renderer in your test, but that doesn't mock *all* the renderers. Only the mock created in the test. The directive uses a different instance of Renderer2, which is not mocked.

Comment: Thank you , I was able to test by creating dummy Component with html template having reference to  @Input element. it is working fine.There is no need to mock the Renderer2 instance for testing this.

Answer (score 0):

@Component({
    template: `<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item>
       <div class='list-item' appMenuDropDown  [subMenuContainer]="subMenuList" 
        mat-list-item>test1
       <span>test2 </span>
       </div>
    </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
    <mat-nav-list>
    <ul #subMenuList>
        <li>child1</li>
        <li>child2</li>
    </ul>
  </mat-nav-list>`,
  styles: ['mat-list-item { display: block; }']

})

class TestMenuDropDownComponent {

}

Answer (score 0):

```
it('TestCase: appMenuDropDown Directive appendChild',fakeAsync(() => {
    const debugEl: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const inputEl: HTMLElement = debugEl.querySelector('.list-item');
    inputEl.click();
    console.log(inputEl.children.length);
    expect(inputEl.children.length).toBeGreaterThan(1)
    tick();
    inputEl.click();
    expect(inputEl.children.length).toEqual(1);
}));
```